# Excel Indirect function using a relative reference to refer to the column

Tags: microsoft-excel

The formula =INDIRECT("A"&B2) refers to cell A{B2}. For example, if you type “x” in cell A9, then 9 in cell B2, and the formula=INDIRECT("A"&B2) in cell C4, this will populate cell C4 with “x”.
But if you copied this formula then the reference to column A is absolute so while B2 may change "A" will remain the same. How do you make it a relative reference?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? There may be ways to avoid using `INDIRECT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula `=INDIRECT("A"&B2)` is volatile, i.e. it will cause a recalculation of the whole workbook when any cell is changed. That can lead to considerable slowness and is one of the reasons why INDIRECT should be avoided, if possible.

For your singular formula, a replacement is possible, but without more context nobody can tell if that is what you need for your situation. Your formula can be re-written as

```
=index(A:A,B2)
```

with the same result. If you copy that formula, you can control whether or not the references are absolute or relative using the $ sign. `$A:$A` copied across will not change, `A:A` copied to the right will change to `B:B`.